# Django - Using single list objects from a model class

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

---

So Create_Watchlist is a model with a Foreignkey to the User Model and 'ticker' is a CharField of Create_Watchlist. Here is my views.py function for the approach

```
def watchlist_one(request, pk):
    Create_Watchlist.objects.get(id=pk)
    list_ticker = list(Create_Watchlist.objects.all().values_list('ticker', flat=True))
```

---

At the moment list_ticker equals ['AAPL, BTC']
I want to access in this case 'AAPL' and 'BTC' as different list objects, because I want to make an API request with each list item. The list_ticker variable changes with the users input from a form . So there could be smt like ['AAPL, BTC'], but as well smt like ['FB'] (etc.)

---

If I've made a mistake here, an explanation of how to deal with query sets and data types would also help me!

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can use a `for` loop, so `for ticker in list_ticker:`.

Comment: `Create_Watchlist` seems to be a bad name for a model. If it is something different from a `Watchlist`, can you explain what it is?

Comment: Also, you say "The list_ticker variable changes with the users input from a form." What exactly do you mean? The `watchlist_one()` function is called with a `pk` that it gets from the form? What do you mean by "I want to access 'AAPL' and 'BTC' as different list objects"?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides  Yes I was already thinking about to rename it into Watchlist. It's just a Watchlist. Actually I meant a ModelForm, so that a user is able to do standard CRUD operations with the model. The pk is from the model itself. It has a ForeignKey to user so every User can have multiple watchlists. To your last question; I need to figure out how I can transform this queryset to work with each ticker (The comma seperated parts of the queryset) f.ex. 'AAPL' on different api request. So that 'AAPL' is parsed as var into an api request and 'BTC' into another one.